# How can I fix 404 error when trying to "Add to Cart" in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: drupal, commerce

We've moved a site from one server to another and don't usually do any work with Drupal - all looked to be working fine on the site but the Add to Cart function is failing - it brings up a 404 error with this response

{"message":"The \u0022commerce_order\u0022 parameter was not converted for the path \u0022/cart/{commerce_order}\u0022 (route name: \u0022rest.commerce_cart_canonical.GET\u0022)"}

The site is llangollenbrewery.com

I can't find any answers to this online so hoping someone can point me in the right direction as it must be a config error somewhere I'd imagine.

Let me know if you have any questions, any help would be much appreciated so the site can take orders again ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work for me. Are there specific items that can't be added? Looks like it's using commerce_cart_flyout module. I tried to change quantity in the flyout and that failed. 405 method not allowed on https://llangollenbrewery.com/cart/XXX/items?_format=json . You may review the RESTful services and make sure the right ones are enabled. I would think Flyout requires that for installation; maybe someone changed it after the fact?

Comment: Thanks Brian, managed to get it fixed now through hiring a developer so all is working, the qty issue was a hosting restriction which is also fixed